# state management using ngrx/store and ngrx/effects in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working on a sample Angular 2 application , and I am planning to use @ngrx/store and @ngrx/effects for state management.

This sample application has a root module and multiple feature modules.

Now my questions are.

1. Can I import StoreModule and EffectsModule in all my feature modules 
   OR 
   Should they be imported only once in root module ?
2. In order to import a single effects file in a module I had written below line of code in module file

   ```
   EffectsModule.run(AuthorEffects)
   ```

   What if there are multiple effect files ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it should be imported in the root module. It looks like the ngrx has a solution in the v3 beta version to provide dynamic reducer functionality:

https://github.com/ngrx/store/pull/269

As far as multiple effects, you will need to call EffectsModule.run() for each effect.

Comment: For example I have the application split in multiple features module (one per page) and each page needs to declare some effects, if I add in each page EffectsModule.run(AuthorEffects) and navigate between 3 pages the effect services will remain active after I leave the page ?

Comment: If I have a copy action which does trigger different effects on different pages the copy action should have a different name on the other page ? Cause if the service is not run after the page is removed then I could use the same action for different effects. What I'm trying to find how is the best to create different actions for each page or to reuse action names on different pages.

Comment: If you are only providing store in the root module, you should register all of the effects there.

Comment: It seems like your real goal is separating actions by pages, in this case I think the best thing to do is create different actions (eg. page1.copy, page2.copy) for each module. You could access the state from the effect to check which page is active if you really want to use the same action and the same effect, but I think it is better practice to use separate actions.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it seems the are few websites with best practices for ngrx used in large applications, cause that's my case and any help is usefull

Comment: no problem. It's also worth joining the gitter at https://gitter.im/ngrx/effects and asking questions there

Answer (score 0):

Very good practice is to import feature modules to root module dynamically.
You can use [ForFeature](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/effect) for this. Your root store is empty from scratch and this is very good for scale your application.

I recommend you investigate this official [sample](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app). It can answer a lot of your questions.

I hope, I helped you.